# understand command in cmd

Tags: command, cmd

> cd /d someDir && pathToJar.exe xf file.zip

this is the command that I want an explanation. as an example,

```
 cd /d c:\rf-jboss_pt2\instance\referral_pt2 && c:\rf-jboss_pt2\java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\jar xf C:\CosmicInstallations\referral-jboss\referral-jboss-dist.zip
```

Comment: This page might help: [jar-The Java Archive Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jar.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to break that down for you. There are two commands separated by &&

&& -- means run the command following && only if the command preceding the symbol is successful.

The first command:

```
cd /d c:\rf-jboss_pt2\instance\referral_pt2   

cd = change directory
/d = also cahnge drive 
c:\rf-jboss_pt2\instance\referral_pt2   is the new path
```

If this is successful, the second command runs:

```
c:\rf-jboss_pt2\java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\jar xf C:\CosmicInstallations\referral-jboss\referral-jboss-dist.zip

c:\rf-jboss_pt2\java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\jar is the name of the command (it could be a .bat, .exe or .com file)

xf = a command line parameter
C:\CosmicInstallations\referral-jboss\referral-jboss-dist.zip = a command line parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /d someDir && anotherDir xf file.zip
```

`cd /d someDir` means change the current directory to someDir.

`&&` : it's and operator

`anotherDir` : execute command from anotherDir

`xf` : the option

`file.zip` : the parameter

So

```
cd /d c:\rf-jboss_pt2\instance\referral_pt2 && c:\rf-jboss_pt2\java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\jar xf C:\CosmicInstallations\referral-jboss\referral-jboss-dist.zip
```

Means : Change current directory to `c:\rf-jboss_pt2\instance\referral_pt2` and then run command from `c:\rf-jboss_pt2\java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin\jar` with option xf and the parameter is `C:\CosmicInstallations\referral-jboss\referral-jboss-dist.zip`